# Insert something between elements generated with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

What would be the best way, to append an element in between elements generated using ng-repeat?

For example:

```
<div class="block" ng-repeat="position in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">{{position+1}}</div>
```

I would like to put a `<br>` **after** every 4th element. My guess would be to create a directive with the `link.post`. Tell me if I'm on the good track.

Thank you

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPMZU/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with the `<br>` but if your are trying to stack them in groups of four then you can do something using the [$index variable from ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) and a class change.

JSFiddle with this: http://jsfiddle.net/y44Cb/13/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{block: ($index +1) % 4}" ng-repeat="position in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
    <div class="red-block">{{position+1}}</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.red-block {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
div.block {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. The reason why I need this is because I have to dynamically generate elements inside of a poorly written layout and it easily break if it exceed a too large value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end and then check whether you want to render the break in a function.

```
<div class="block" ng-repeat-start="position in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
        <div class="red-block">{{position+1}}</div>
</div>
```

with

```
<br ng-if="includeBreak(position)" ng-repeat-end>
```

or

```
<p ng-if="includeBreak(position)" ng-repeat-end></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ng-switch to do what you need

```
<div class="block" ng-repeat="position in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" data-ng-switch on="($index + 1) % 4 == 0 && $index > 0">
    {{position+1}}
    <br data-ng-switch-when="true">
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qrne/ if you inspect the "5" div you'll see it has the 
 same with the "9" div, but none of the others.

Comment: Do you know how to insert the <br> after?

Comment: Do you mean outside of the ngRepeat? If so you'd have to do some messy things with creating a separate array to loop over that I'd recommend against. James Sharps method would by my suggestion as well.